# Can any JS expert look at the my code and told what i am doing wrong

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can  any one help me to understand the following code. i am creating the folder using the mkdirp-promise in the nodejs . what the difference between the followig code

```
1) mkdirp('/hello2')
    .then(console.log("hello")) 
    .catch(console.error)

2)    mkdirp("/test").then(() => {
    console.log("directory made");
    console.log("hello");
    }).catch(console.error);
```

1) when i run the first code i get the hello inside the console and also the hello2 folder is created 
2) But when i run the second one the folder test is created but i did't get the log why ?? i have to use the 2nd case

Comment: The first console log is being evaluated immediately as it is an expression, not a function. What you mean to write was

    .then(() => console.log("hello"))

Comment: @dev i have to do some async logic after the folder is created .

Comment: What you get in second case ??

Comment: @Shubh noting, but the folder is created

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using async/await to make your code cleaner.

```js
try {
 await mkdirp('/hello2');
 console.log('hello');
 await mkdirp("/test");
 console.log("directory made");
} catch (error) {
 console.error(error);
}
```

or else

```js
mkdirp('/hello2')
 .then(() => {
   console.log('hello');
   return mkdirp("/test");
 })
 .then(() => {
   console.log("directory made");
 })
 .catch(console.error);
```